# NSForm disappearing from custom sheet

Tags: cocoa, autoresize, cocoa-sheet, nsform

I've made a custom sheet and it appears and disappears as necessary. However, the sheet includes an NSForm that disappears when automatic cell resizing is disabled.

When "Auto recalculate cell size" is enabled, the form appears but the form's cells are not sized properly.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with auto layout. I just disabled it for the sheet. Worked fine after that.